# OpenCV for Unity - HoughLines returning no lines

Tags: java, c#, opencv, unity-game-engine

I am currently using OpenCV for Unity3d (OpenCV for Java with a C# wrapper). I am trying to get lines using HoughLines but it's always empty.

```
Mat originalToPlaywith = Room.OriginalRGB;
Mat dst = new Mat();
Mat cdst = new Mat();

Imgproc.Canny(originalToPlaywith, dst, 50.0, 200);
Imgproc.cvtColor(dst, cdst, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGRA);

Mat lines = new Mat();
Imgproc.HoughLines(dst, lines, Mathf.PI / 180, 150, 0);

Debug.Log(lines.rows());

double[] data;
double rho;
double theta;
Point pt1 = new Point();
Point pt2 = new Point();
double a;
double b;
double x0;
double y0;

for(int i = 0; i < lines.cols(); i++)
{
    data = lines.get(0, i);
    rho = data[0];
    theta = data[1];
    a = Math.Cos(theta);
    b = Math.Sin(theta);
    x0 = a * rho;
    y0 = b * rho;
    pt1.x = Math.Round(x0 + 1000 * (-b));
    pt1.y = Math.Round(y0 + 1000 * a);
    pt2.x = Math.Round(x0 - 1000 * (-b));
    pt2.y = Math.Round(y0 - 1000 * a);
    Scalar color = new Scalar(10, 10, 10, 10);
    Core.line(dst, pt1, pt2, color, 3);
    Debug.LogWarning("Line");
}
```

Won't let me post images just yet so links included.

Original Image [Unaltered Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdCTs.jpg)

Canny Image [Canny Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4bgw.png)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: input argument 150 seems a little too much. Try setting it to default value (0). Also show the canny'd image, and check the you actually have some lines.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that and see what happens!